# Removing event.preventDefault on click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, preventdefault

I have this code which prevents default behavior on all elements:

```
$('body *').click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Now I would like to programmatically click a certain link in the page but first I have to remove the  `e.preventDefault();` so I used `unbind`:

```
$('a')[0].unbind('click');
$('a')[0].click();
```

This doesn't work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you give a sample of the html you are trying to change?

Comment: "*What am I doing wrong?*" - you're chaining a jQuery method to a DOM node: this will not work. @Youss: no, it doesn't work: it fails at `$('a')[0].unbind('click');`

Comment: @David Thomas That actually works: http://jsfiddle.net/pg2z4zLa/2/ Or did you mean the unbind part?

Comment: You can't do `$('a')[0].unbind('click')` do `.eq(0).unbind('click')`

Comment: @Beau Bouchard What makes you think I want to change HTML...?

Comment: @Anton Thank you very much that worked:) If you place an answer I accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do

```
$('a')[0].unbind('click')
```

use `.eq()` to get the first element and then unbind

```
.eq(0).unbind('click')
```