# Jquery unbind does not work for advanced/multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, unbind

I have a simple HTML link and Jquery code which prevents default in the first place. But then I undo the `preventDefault` with Jquery `unbind`

```
$('body *').click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
});


$('a').eq(0).unbind('click');
$('a')[0].click();
```

This works good. However when I wrape the link in a paragraph like this:

```
<p><a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
```

It doesn't work anymore when I specify the selectors like this:

```
  $('p a').eq(0).unbind('click');
```

What is so special about adding this extra selector?

Example at JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nb9Lck5p/2/

Comment: The code in  your demo has `e.stopPropagation()` but the code in your question doesn't. Why? And do you understand the difference between `.eq(0)` and `[0]`? And what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: This sure looks similar to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239304/removing-event-preventdefault-on-click-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because of event propagation... you are removing the click handler from `a`, but it is still present in `p`(the parent element), so when the event is bubbled to the parent element its click handler is called which is calling the prevent default thus preventing the default behavior from of link click

By stopping event propagation

```js
$('body *').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});


$('p a').eq(0).unbind('click').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$('p a')[0].click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a>
</p>
```

---

But the way you have used unbind is dangerous because it will remove any other click handler bound to the `a` element, use [namespacing](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) instead

```js
$('body *').on('click.myhandler', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
});


$('p a').eq(0).off('click.myhandler').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('p a')[0].click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a>
</p>
```

Comment: @Youss yes... but that is from the parent.. in this case from the `p` element not from the `a`

Comment: I think your info is incorrect @ArunPJohny, in this case the event was not binded on `p` or `a`, it was binded on `body *`. It works like "trigger click on `body *`, and it check `(function(e){if($(e.target) == $('p a') || $(e.target).closest('p a').length > 0) { triggerFunction();} })` . So, he bind event on `body *`, he must unbind event on `body *`.

Comment: @JhKaiz I don't think OP wants to remove the click handler from the `p` element

Comment: no, that's not what I want to tell you. Check my solution over there please :D, hope it help you understand my idea :D.

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle, you bind event on `('body *')`, but you unbind 'click' event on `'p a'` selector. In this case, you must unbind/off the event on `'body *'` , not `'p'`, or `'a'`.

```
$('p a:first').on('click', function(e){
    alert('click');
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('p a:first').off('click');
$('p a')[0].click();
```

I recommend you use `.on`, `.off`, than `.bind`, `.unbind`